# Cocos2D - userData property for sprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a iphone game app using Cocos2d.

I find this is an excellent solution to my problem of storage an integer to the sprite's property:

sprite.userData = 123;

However, sprite.userData can store only one piece data. If I need to store three pieces of data, what is the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

'userData' is actually void pointer not retained by the 'Node' class:

```
void *userData_;
```

As such it can points to any data structure or class (or even a C function).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet, for one or nine custom variables, is to subclass CCSprite and have your custom variables as class variables of the new class, using properties to read/write them publicly.

Like a well-versed Objective-C programmer would do.

To explicitly answer your question: You can set an NSDictionary or NSArray to userData, which themselves can contain more than one item. But if you're going that far: read above.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the ccsprite class into userdata class and use that class for any no of variables you want to create... however you will need to use that class for all checks and conditions ....

Here take the code

Userdata.h

```
//
//  UserData.h
//
//


#import "CCSprite.h"
#import "Constants.h"

@class GameLayer;
@interface UserData : CCSprite {
    int userDataType;
    int tag;
    int parentTag;
      GameLayer *gameLayer;
    BOOL readyForDeletion; 
}

@property(nonatomic) int userDataType;
@property(nonatomic) int tag;
@property(nonatomic) int parentTag;
@property(nonatomic, assign) GameLayer *gameLayer;
@property(nonatomic) BOOL readyForDeletion;

-(id) initWithSpriteName:(NSString *)spriteName;

@end
```

and the userdata.mm

```
    //
   //  UserData.mm
   //
   //

   #import "UserData.h"

   @implementation UserData

   @synthesize userDataType;
   @synthesize tag;
   @synthesize parentTag;
   @synthesize gameLayer;
   @synthesize readyForDeletion;

   -(id) initWithSpriteName:(NSString *)spriteName {
       if (self = [super initWithFileName:spriteName]) {

       }
       return self;
   }

   -(void) onExit {
       [super onExit];
   }

   -(void) dealloc {
       [super dealloc];
   }
```

@end